# Is there an advantage to moving to 'real' date partitions on MySQL 5.5?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, partitioning, mysql-5.1

We are using partitions per day for some our tables. We started with MySQL 5.1, so we had to partition using the to_days (`end_time` is a `datetime` column):

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE ( to_days(end_time))
(PARTITION p20130521 VALUES LESS THAN (735375) ENGINE = InnoDB,
....
PARTITION p20130603 VALUES LESS THAN (735388) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p20130604 VALUES LESS THAN (735389) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p20130605 VALUES LESS THAN (735390) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p20130606 VALUES LESS THAN (735391) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p99991230 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Starting with MySQL 5.5, it is now possible to avoid the `to_days` and partition by real dates. Is there any (speed) advantage to doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using [to_days](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) to Partition

The [to_days](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) function yields a 6 digit number in the 700,000's (in the MEDUIMINT range).

## Using DATE or DATETIME to Partition

DATE takes up 3 bytes. DATETIME takes up 8 bytes.

## Conjecture

[**UNIX_TIMESTAMP**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) of today's date exceeds 1.37 billion. It takes 4 bytes to store that. Range partitioning allows for range values that high. Here is an [**example of that from the MySQL Documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-range.html):

> It is also possible to partition a table by RANGE, based on the value
> of a TIMESTAMP column, using the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function, as shown
> in this example:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE quarterly_report_status (
>     report_id INT NOT NULL,
>     report_status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
>     report_updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
> )
> PARTITION BY RANGE ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(report_updated) ) (
>     PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-01-01 00:00:00') ),
>     PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-04-01 00:00:00') ),
>     PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-07-01 00:00:00') ),
>     PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-10-01 00:00:00') ),
>     PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-01-01 00:00:00') ),
>     PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-04-01 00:00:00') ),
>     PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-07-01 00:00:00') ),
>     PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-10-01 00:00:00') ),
>     PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-01-01 00:00:00') ),
>     PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
> );
> ```

Partitions seem to be numerically represented as a 4-byte unsigned integer. As mentioned, `DATE` takes up 3 bytes, but, from what I have observed, partitions are bounded by 4-byte numbers. Given this, expressing a `DATE` as a `RANGE` parameter really does not buy you anything except cleaner syntax for defining the range.

Expressing [to_days](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) of a DATE yourself or having mysql do it for you boils down to personal choice.